# How to extract rows in pandas dataframe into a dict that corresponds to given time?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` that has columns: `id`, `time`, `val`.

Each `id` has multiple rows, where each row is sorted according to increasing `time`. Time is an `int`. `id` is also an `int`. `val` is a `float`.

e.g.,

```
id   time  val
0    1     2.3
0    2     3.0
0    5     8.0
1    1     5.1
1    2     7.8
.......
```

Given a time `t`, I need to return a `dict` that stores `id: val` pairs at the given `t`.

e.g., `t = 2`, return `{0: 3.0; 1: 7.8}`

I am wondering if there's a built-in way to do this with pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dict comp

```
mapping = {k: v.groupby("id")["val"].apply(list).to_dict() for k, v in df.reset_index("time").groupby("time")}
print(mapping.get(2))
```

Output:

```
{0: [3.0], 1: [7.8]}
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

```
dict(df.loc[df.time.eq(2), ['id', 'val']].to_records(index=False))
```

---

Another possible solution:

```
aux = df.loc[df.time.eq(2), ['id', 'val']]
dict(zip(aux.id, aux.val))
```

---

Output:

```
{0: 3.0, 1: 7.8}
```

Comment: In my codebase it seems `id` and `time` are set as indices in the dataframe. Is your snippet easily adaptable to this?

Comment: Yes, @roulette01, my both solutions seem to work, even when `id` and `time` are together in the index of the dataframe.

Comment: I think you can't do `df.time` if `time` is the index? I am getting `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'time'`

Comment: Then, in my code, use `df.reset_index()` instead of `df` -- it should work!

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
t = 2
df.loc[df.time.eq(t)].set_index('id')['val'].to_dict()
```

output:

```
{0: 3.0, 1: 7.8}
```

In case you have multiindex i.e. your `id` and `time` are both indices.

Then if your index order is `['id', 'time']` then you can do:

```
t = 2
df.loc[(slice(None), t), :].reset_index('time')['val'].to_dict()
```

if your index order is `['time', 'id']` then:

```
t = 2
df.loc[(t, slice(None)), :].reset_index('time')['val'].to_dict()
```

Comment: What if `id` and `time` were already set as indices? That appears to be the case in the codebase I'm working with

Comment: You can reset the time index to column first.
df = df.reset_index("time").query("time.eq(2)")["val"].to_dict()